# ARCore OpenGL framebuffer error (1286)

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, arcore

I'm trying to use framebuffer in OpenGL to get an output texture out of a shader and use it in another shader in order to achieve blur effect.

I followed these tutorials to add frame buffers in my project.
http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/
http://opengles2learning.blogspot.com/2014/02/render-to-texture-rtt.html

As a result I have:

```
int[] temp = new int[1];
int FramebufferName = 0;
GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, temp, FramebufferName);
fboID = temp[0];
GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);

GLES20.glGenRenderbuffers(1, temp, FramebufferName);
int renderBufferId = temp[0];
GLES20.glBindRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, FramebufferName);
GLES20.glRenderbufferStorage(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, 1080, 1920);
GLES20.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 
GLES20.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBufferId);
GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, newTextureID2, 0);
```

in the initialization.

and in OnDrawFrame method I have:

```
GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);
GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, 1080, 1920);
```

But I get glError 1286 which is invalid frame buffer error. I think the problem maybe related to the texture not being power of 2. However my camera from ARCore returns 1080 x 1920. I'm getting the camera data as a bitmap by using glreadPixel. Is there a way to modify the dimension of the bitmap or the camera from ARCore?

**EDIT:**
I actually checked for glerror after buffer initialization and I'm getting glError 1282. I'm not sure what's wrong now.

Comment: Have you checked that your framebuffer is complete?

Comment: @Reaper Yes I checked using
  `int e = GLES20.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
if (e != GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
                            Log.e("Main", "Framebuffer not complete");
                        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achieved framebuffer by using render-to-texture instead of using Renderbuffer.

Here's my working framebuffer initialization:

```
mFrameBuffers = new int[1];
mFrameBufferTextures = new int[1];

GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, mFrameBuffers, 0);
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, mFrameBufferTextures, 0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mFrameBufferTextures[0]);
GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, width, height, 0,
        GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, mFrameBuffers[0]);
GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
        GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mFrameBufferTextures[0], 0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Also this problem had nothing to do with ARCore.
Hope this helps someone!